# XWPFDocument - getPageCount

Tags: java, apache-poi

For old Microsoft formats (.doc) APACHE POI used HWPFDocument. To know the number of pages for this object, I just needed to do:

```
 HWPFDocument document = new HWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath()));
            System.out.println(document.getSummaryInformation().getPageCount());
```

Now, I want to do the same to XWPFDocument (for .docx), but this method do not exist.

I tried:

```
XWPFWordExtractor extractor = new XWPFWordExtractor(document);
```

and see if it has something similar to getPageCount() but i did not found anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I cannot test it but I suggest try this:

```
XWPFDocument docx = new XWPFDocument(POIXMLDocument.openPackage(DocFilePath));

int numPages = docx.getProperties().getExtendedProperties().getUnderlyingProperties().getPages();
```

https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/POIXMLProperties.ExtendedProperties.html

Comment: Returning 0 for me

Answer (score 0):

From a [XWPFWordExtractor](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/extractor/XWPFWordExtractor.html), you can get the page count by doing:

```
XWPFWordExtractor extractor = new XWPFWordExtractor(document);
int pageCount = extractor.getExtendedProperties().getPages();
```

Details, such that they are, in [this](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/extractor/XWPFWordExtractor.html) and [this](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/POIXMLProperties.ExtendedProperties.html#getPages%28%29) bit of the Apache POI javadocs

Comment: this is returning -1 for me

Comment: @HenriqueSchmitt This returns the value that Word saved in the file metadata. Word doesn't always opt to calculate/save one though, and nor do some third party libraries

Comment: I found the problem, the file that I was reading inside the application was downloaded from google drive. so the soluttion was open the file in microsoft word, and save again, and that fixed the problem